# "dbo_" Missing From DNS-Less Connected Tables

Tags: vba, ms-access, connection-string

I've had a DNS-less connection to my SQL Servers for years... but all of a sudden some (not all) of the tables are coming across WITHOUT the "dbo_" in the table name.  I need the "dbo_" in the table names.  It doesn't affect all the tables, just some of them.  What's interesting is that it's the same tables that get the "dbo_" and the same ones that do not get it.

All tablenames in the table start with "dbo_".  Nothing has changed in the DB nor the server for years.  It's a 2019 SQL Server.

Any ideas on why its doing this?

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Login
    
    Dim varUserName As String
    Dim varPassword As String
    Dim vardim As String
    Dim varCreds As String
    
    varUserName = Me.txtUserName
    varPassword = Nz(Me.txtPassword, vbNullString)
    varCreds = "UID=" & varUserName & ";PWD=" & varPassword
    vardim = ";APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=xyz"
    
    strConnection = "ODBC;Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=xyz;" & varCreds & ";APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=xyz"
    
    Dim dbCurrent As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
    Set dbCurrent = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set qdf = dbCurrent.CreateQueryDef("")
    
    Dim td As TableDef

    'Columns in ActiveTablesToLink: (DatabaseName, LinkFlag, LocalTableName, ServerName, SSTableName)    
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM ActiveTablesToLink WHERE LinkFlag = -1 And DatabaseName = 'xyz'"
    
    Set recLocal = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strsql)
    
    recLocal.MoveLast
    recLocal.MoveFirst
    
    strRecCount = recLocal.RecordCount
    
    If strRecCount > 0 Then

        Do While Not recLocal.EOF
        
        stLocalTableName = recLocal!LocalTableName
        stRemoteTableName = recLocal!SSTableName
        
            Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, strConnection)
            
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
            
            recLocal.MoveNext
            
        Loop
        
    Else
    
    End If 'Empty recordset
    
    recLocal.Close
    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
    
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Login"

Exit_cmdLogin: ' Label to resume after error.
      Exit Sub
      
Err_Login:
If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 1 Then
    'ODBC Error
    For Each errany In DBEngine.Errors
        MsgBox "ODBCExecute: Err# " & errany.Number & " raised by " _
         & errany.Source & ": " & errany.Description, _
         vbCritical, "cmdExecuteAttached()"
    Next errany
Else  'Access Error
    MsgBox "ODBCExecute: Err# " & Err.Number & " raised by " _
     & Err.Source & ": " & Err.Description, _
     vbCritical, "cmdExecuteAttached()"
End If
    Resume Exit_cmdLogin
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Eh... You're pulling those table names from a table. We can't tell you why those names don't have dbo_ in front of them in that table.

Comment: they all have "dbo_" in front of them; here are some examples:
dbo_UserInfo, dbo_Address, dbo_AcctProfile

Comment: Well, this code is pulling names from that table. Please try to create a [mre], if table names that aren't in the table are being used, I have a hard time believing this code is the problem

Comment: So the problem is showing up in `stLocalTableName` and `SSTableName` ? Are those values being queried from a local Access table, or is that a SQL server-linked table?  You might provide a bit more information about exactly where things are going astray.

Comment: Yes the LocalTableName is held in a local table called ActiveTablesToLink.  The problem is the LocalTableName, for some reason the linked table doesn't always get the "dbo_" in front of it, sometimes it does.  The data (tablenames) inside the table are perfect.
When I step through the code and Debug.Print everything the data is passed exactly as it should.

Comment: This is happening to every single database in the company.  It's not just one Access file.  I have 14 files in total over 3 companies in the building.

This is also happening on all my test SQL Servers.  I've tried the old "SQL Server" driver, does the same thing.

I just renamed a table to "dbo_dbo_Address"  and it came over "dbo_dbo_Address" but when I change it back to "dbo_Address" the "dbo_" is gone and it just comes over as "Address"

Comment: Is this your question?  It looks very similar...  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/has-version-2212-of-ms-access-affected-attaching/e730184f-db94-4fa8-b144-491c638df87c

Comment: Tim you found the problem yes - awesome job finding that; Microsoft screwed this up!!!!  Until they put a fix out this week for version 2301 - I have to now go into every single DB front end and put code that says if the table doesn't start with dbo_ then rename it... I'm so f'ing pissed.  I'm the only DBA for a $6B portfolio company and I have 30+ users dead in the water?!

Comment: Here is the code I had to put in above the Append:     

td.Name = stLocalTableName 'this fixes the Name member that wasn’t correctly set

Comment: Interesting, so the name is ignored when creating it? That's certainly new and might affect some of my databases as well, guess I'm lucky that I deferred that update. Microsoft's track record keeping Access maintained is not great... Consider adding the workaround and link as an answer, it's sure to earn you some rep

Comment: It has been fixed in the [upcoming update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/some-tables-do-not-get-named-with-the-dbo-prefix-when-using-vba-createtabledef-in-access-for-microsoft-365-e31bc63c-b112-452b-9f09-7838eca3ce1f?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: So I just wanted to follow up as "Version 2301 Build 16.0.16026.20002" has indeed fixed this bug.  I lost an entire day of total black out production because of this bug, very unsettling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where you put the code just in case you need to fix this via VBA:

```
            Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, strConnection)

            ' Add this line before he append
            td.Name = stLocalTableName

            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
            
            recLocal.MoveNext
```

Thanks to Tim Williams to finding the bug article:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/has-version-2212-of-ms-access-affected-attaching/e730184f-db94-4fa8-b144-491c638df87c